# Export app state from application, like dev tools - React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, export, devtools

I want export state of all application in React component to file, like it's done with Redux Devtools. 
[Export button in Redux devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41NvE.png)

Maybe there's any library to do the same from code level?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can check React context, redux use context to share state between components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html